# Is is possible to modify the Alternate Data Stream (ADS) in MS Word with Protected View?

Tags: office, alternative-data-streams

Is it possible to modify the Alternate Data Stream (ADS) to prevent `.docx` to be opened in Protected View for files downloaded from Internet.

> When is Protected View used?
>
> Since Protected View is a read only view, we understand it is not
>   something that should be used for every file you interact with. Our
>   goal when designing this feature was to only use it in high risk
>   scenarios:
>
> 1. Files opened from the Internet. When a file is downloaded
>      from the Internet the Windows Attachment Execution Service places a
>      marker in the file’s alternate data stream to indicate it came from
>      the Internet zone. When a Word, Excel or PowerPoint file is opened and
>      has this marker it will open in Protected View until the user decides
>      to trust and edit it.
>
> ...

Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office2010/2009/08/13/protected-view-in-office-2010/

I know how to disable Protected View on my laptop. I'm asking how to prevent Protected View to be triggered when sending a `.docx` to a person.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials explaining how to disable Protected View, like [this](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-protected-view-microsoft-wor). Moreover, why are you mentioning ADS?

Comment: Got it. I suggest you to add the quote from Technet related to ADS in your question, so to make it more clear.

Comment: Now the post is not readable at all. Consider this thread as closed. I'm to old for this correction / formatting bull****.